# Redirecting output from R - doesn't seem to work for library(moments)

Tags: r, grep, output, stdout, stderr

I'm trying to get a clean output, using the cli (bash). It mainly works - but, for some reason, I can't catch the output from 'library(moments)':

> ```
>    (R --slave 2>/dev/null <<@@END
>     options(install.packages.check.quiet = "true")
>     install.packages("moments",repos = "https://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/")
>     library(moments)
>         
>     speeds <- read.csv("/users/somebody/speeds")
>     length <- dim(speeds)[1]
>
>     cat("\t\t\t\tSpeed stats:\nNumber of readings:\t",length,"\n")
> ```
>
> cat("Min:\t\t\t",min(speeds),"\nMax:\t\t\t",max(speeds),"\nMean:\t\t\t",mean(speeds[,1]),"\nStandard
> Deviation:\t",sd(speeds[,1]),"\nMedian:\t\t\t",median(speeds[,1]),"\nFivenum:\t\t",fivenum(speeds[,1]),"\n"
> )
>
> ```
>     cat("Skewness:\t\t",skewness(speeds[,1]),"\nKurtosis:\t\t", kurtosis(speeds[,1]),"\n")
>
>     @@END )|grep -v "binary|moments"
> ```

The redirection of stderr to /dev/null doesn't catch it, and the redirection of the output into grep doesn't catch it.

Instead, the output includes:

> There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
> binary source needs_compilation moments   0.14 0.14.1             FALSE

Comment: The first part of your message comes from `install.packages()` and would be avoided if you specified the type you want, e.g. `install.packages("moments",repos = "https://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/", type = "binary")`.  Also, the option you gave looks wrong:  I think it should be `options(install.packages.check.source = "no")`.